# Code coverage in E2E test on .NET kubernetes microservices?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, microservices, code-coverage

Our company has an async API based on a REST endpoint service that sends messages to a processor service that then dispatches messages to one of several worker services. It's a very solid architecture that is resilient to faults, easy to extend, and solves our problems and use cases very well.

We have an extensive E2E test suite that runs queries against the test environment deployment of the entire microservice architecture. This means that in running our tests in an Azure pipeline, all the tests are actually REST calls to the test microservice endpoint. This test suite itself works very well, but I've been tasked with making code coverage analysis of it, and that is where the problem begins.

My question is: how do I go about making the worker microservices produce code coverage instrumentation? Ideally I want them to produce this coverage data only while the E2E test is running, and then afterwards collect and collate it. I will also accept them simply always generating coverage and then resetting the data before each E2E test run.

So far most of the articles I can find are either to do with Java, or not related to the problem at hand.